# How to bring popup window in front of dialog

Tags: android, layout, dialog, popupwindow

Every time I want to show PopupWindow in front of dialog fragment, the dialog is in front of the popup.I assume that dialogs have higher priority in view tree.Is there any option to bring my PopupWindow to the front, or send dialog to back.bringToFront() is not working when It's called on View detailsLayout.

Here is a method for showing PopupWindow inside of Fragment, and it's working good on all screens:

```
  private void showDetailsTutorial() {
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(getActivity());
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.popup_parent);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
        (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View detailsLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_copy_confirmation_layout, viewGroup);

    popupWindow.setContentView(layout);
    popupWindow.setWidth(1080);
    popupWindow.setHeight(1000);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(continueBtn, Gravity.TOP, 0, 250);
    AutoResizeTextView skip = (AutoResizeTextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.skip);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View view) {
        popupWindow.dismiss();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I faced similar issue, ended up adding another dialog fragment

Comment: @VK.N If I create another dialog fragment called dialog2, Can user click through dialog2, so onClick from dialog1 is called.

Answer (score 0):

use WindowManager to show any layout as you want.

```
private void showDetailsTutorial() {
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.popup_parent);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
        (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View detailsLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_copy_confirmation_layout, viewGroup);
    
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.BOTTOM;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    
    windowManager.addView(detailsLayout, params);
    
    }
```